# Creating Dynamic Profile Graph for Data Driven Page Atlas using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, data-driven-pages, graph, dynamic

I used **Strip Map Index Features** tool to create a **Data Driven Page** set of maps and I would need to create a new data frame that will contain a dynamic profile graph that will be modify depending on section of line for each page of the map Atlas displayed.

I have my 3D line and DEM and know how to create a profile graph for the whole line with 3D Analyst. But I'm lost when I have to create a graph for each page of the book and make that data frame dynamic at the same time.

Comment: To do so I am using 2 elements: data frame with main map and graph element below it.
First task is to create profiles, using arcpy script, export it as attachment to data driven pages, all very similar to one described here  http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/162907/labeling-points-with-numbers-and-adding-text-label-to-legend-as-list-in-arcmap/163919#163919 I have a script for this. Are you familiar with python?

Answer (score 2):

We are using New Century's Sheet Cutter for this.

http://www.newcenturysoftware.com/products/sheetcutter.html

I think it could also be achieved with Python, but it may take sometime to develop...