# Dynamic DEM Profile Graphs for Data Driven Pages in ArcGIS Desktop or ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, data-driven-pages, graph, dynamic

I came accross this topic [Dynamic Profile Graph for Data Driven Page Atlas](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/166828/dynamic-profile-graph-for-data-driven-page-atlas#comment248258_166828)

5 years on and this functionality still does not seem to be built into ArcGIS Desktop or ArcGIS Pro. Does anybody know good web code and workflow description source to share?

I have multiple DEM surfaces that I want to show the profiles for in a single graph that is linked to Data Driven Page.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  Please check out our short [tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  To make your question suitable for re-opening you would first need to focus it on ArcGIS Pro.

Comment: However, since you are looking for code we ask that you show us where you are stuck with your own code by including a [code snippet](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4312) in your question.  There is an [edit] button beneath your question which will enable you to do that and a **`{}`** button that enables you to format any highlighted code nicely.

Comment: To do this without code using ArcGIS Pro it may be worth investigating Map Series and Chart Frames.

Comment: These are your [Options when question is duplicate of one with no/inadequate/old answers](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4010).