# relocate key numbering list on layout

Tags: arcgis-desktop, labeling

I am creating a map of local authorities in Hampshire, UK and due to size, key numbering is the best option to clearly label. 
The list, however, is not in an ideal location. Is there a way to relocate the list to another area of the map layout?

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the key numbering list [to annotation](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/map/working-with-text/converting-labels-to-annotation.htm) and position it that way. However, if you need to change the numbers or order in the future it could become a bit of a pain. There's some other really good answers on this [GIS SE](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/162907/labeling-points-with-numbers-and-adding-text-label-to-legend-as-list-in-arcmap/162919) that involve sample scripts and work arounds for a similar scenario you have.